# Twitter Bootstrap carousel - move indicators

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to move my carousel indicators beneath the carousel. I've tried a few tips on the web to no avail.

I tried bottom with a negative value, but no good.
Any suggestions?

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <img src="/bootstrap-3.1.1/images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       ATS International Conference
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="item">
      <img src="/bootstrap-3.1.1/images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       ATS International Conference
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="item">
      <img src="/bootstrap-3.1.1/images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       ATS International Conference
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your indicators where you want...

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/SZqnwXVQ71

**CSS**:

```
.carousel-indicators{
    position:relative;
    background:grey;
    height:25px;
    bottom:0px;
  }
  .carousel-control{
     margin-bottom:25px;   // Same height as indicators
  }
```

**HTML** :

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <img src="/bootstrap-3.1.1/images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       ATS International Conference
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="item">
      <img src="/bootstrap-3.1.1/images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       ATS International Conference
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="item">
      <img src="/bootstrap-3.1.1/images/carousel-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       ATS International Conference
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

  <!-- Indicators JUST MOVE IT DOWN-->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do that, the indicators end up at the bottom of my page, and they are no longer clickable. here is a link: [https://store-stg.thoracic.org/index2014.php]

Comment: The gray background helps, but I don't want the indicators to show on top of the carousel slide, which they do. I want it totally beneath the carousel.